# QAbstractItemMode , How to get QList<*> varible from abstract data metod

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

I have a class which hold first , last and sub(QList). Example:

```
   class DataObject { 
public:
 DataObject(const QString &firstName,
         const QString &lastName,
         const QList<SubObject*>   &sublist):
 first(firstName),
 last(lastName),
 sublist(sublist){}

   QString first;
   QString last;
   QList<SubObject*> sublist;
};
```

I can't build apps after adding QList sublist in this code block:

```
QVariant SimpleListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index,
                                        int role) const {
if (!index.isValid())
    return QVariant(); // Return Null variant if index is invalid
if (index.row() > (m_items.size()-1) )
    return QVariant();

DataObject *dobj = m_items.at(index.row());
switch (role) {
case Qt::DisplayRole: // The default display role now displays the first name as well
case FirstNameRole:
    return QVariant::fromValue(dobj->first);
case LastNameRole:
    return QVariant::fromValue(dobj->last);
case SubListRole:
   return QVariant::fromValue(dobj->sublist);   //this error line
default:
    return QVariant();
}
```

Error is :
**C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:725: error: static assertion failed: Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system
 #define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                               ^**

Comment: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( QList<SubObject*> )`. But be carefull, because you may have problems with tracking lifetime of objects in list.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov thank you. Another porblem is how to refer sublist member to listview delegate.For example: text:sublist[0].lesson

Comment: You may create another question. But before, please, read and learn this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html